# How would I create a function to convert from an integer to std_logic vector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am seeking help as I am learning this language construct.

Here is what I have:

```
function int_slv(val,width: integer) return std_logic_vector is
variable R: std_logic_vector(0 to width-1):=(others=>'0')
variable b:integer:= width;

begin 
   if (b>32) then
      b=32;
   else
      assert 2**bits >val report
      "value too big for std_logic_vector"
      severity warning
   end if;

for i in 0 to b-1 loop
 if val ((val/(2**i)) MOD 2 = 1) then
      R(i)='1';
 end if;
end loop;

return(R);
end int_slv;
```

Comment: When you have used this code, what is going wrong?  You show us your code, but not the exact problem you are trying to solve.  Adding that to your post will help folks figure out how best to help.

Comment: i get this errror,   # Error: COMP96_0016: i2bv.vhd : (7, 10): Design unit declaration expected.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is no one can tell where line 7 is in i2bv.vhd.  It looks like this function body isn't  a declarative item of an entity, a block (incl. architecture), a package body or as one of their various statement declarative items.

Comment: Please add the error to your question, as well as indicating line 7 where it's located.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 5 syntax errors, one wrong identifier and a modulo reduction expressions expressed as an element of an array as well as several sets of redundant parentheses, your modified code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package int2bv_pkg is
    function int_slv (val, width: integer) return std_logic_vector;
end package;
package body int2bv_pkg is
    function int_slv (val, width: integer) return std_logic_vector is
        variable R: std_logic_vector(0 to width-1):=(others=>'0'); -- added ';'
        variable b:integer:= width;
    begin  
        if b > 32 then
            b := 32;   -- ":=" is used for  variable assignment 
        else
            assert 2 ** width > val report  -- width not bits
            "value too big for std_logic_vector"
            severity warning; -- missing semicolon at the end of assertion
        end if;

        for i in 0 to b - 1 loop
            if val/2 ** i MOD 2 = 1 then -- not val (...)
                R(i) := '1';  -- ":=" variable assign.
            end if;
        end loop;
        return R;  -- parentheses not needed
    end int_slv;
end package body int2bv_pkg;
```

analyzes (compiles). The exponentiation operator "**" is the highest priority, the division operators "/" and "mod" are the same priority and executed in the order they are found (left to right). It's likely worthwhile learning VHDL operator precedence.

You were using "=" for variable assignment when you should have been using ":=" in two places, you were missing two semicolons and were using the identifier bits (which isn't declared in your function) where apparently you meant width.

The modified example analyzes, and hasn't been tested absent a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example in the question.

Note that a package body is a design unit as is a package declaration. There are various other places in other design units you can introduce a function body.

You could also note the 2 ** 31 is outside the guaranteed range of an integer in VHDL equal to 2147483648, while the INTEGER value range guaranteed to be from -2147483647 to +2147483647 at a minimum.

This implies that were ever you are using a value that derived from an expression equivalent to 2 ** 31 you can incur a range error during execution (either at elaboration or during simulation).

This pretty much says you need a VHDL implementation with a larger INTEGER value range or you need to rethink what you're doing.

As a matter of course there are integer to unsigned and integer to signed functions found in package numeric_std in library IEEE.
The result of such can be type converted to std_logic_vector, and the source code can make great learning aids on how to wend through the limitations VHDL imposes.  These to_signed or to_unsigned functions would be capable of dealing with the maximum value an INTEGER can hold and specify the length of the resulting array type while providing zero or sign filling for array lengths greater than the INTEGER's binary value. That utility extends to clipping using length as well.

VHDL -2008 package numeric_std_unsigned contains a function To_StdLogicVector that does what your int_slv function is intended to do although limited to a NATURAL range for the integer type input.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1155120 has already indicated, the VHDL-2008 package `numeric_std_unsigned` has a builtin to_stdlogicvector.  And @user1155120 already pointed out the `to_signed` and `to_unsigned` in `numeric_std` are available as well.

So, to expand on the previous answer, you can do:

```
constant C : integer := -6817563;
constant C_VEC : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_signed(c, 32));
```

And this mechanism will accept the full range of `integer`. You can also use `to_unsigned`, but this is limited to the range of `natural`.